# Blazor Web Assembly - Cannot bind to Input in modal popup

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

So I am trying to do the simple, validate a password from a modal popup in Blazor web assembly. Here is the code

```
<div class="simple-form">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="form-label">Password</label>
    <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" bind="_password"/>
    <label class="@_pwordIncorrect alert alert-danger" role="alert">Password incorrect, try again!</label>
    <label class="@_pwordRequired alert alert-danger" role="alert">Password is required</label>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" @onclick="Login">Login</button>
</div>
```

code {

```
[CascadingParameter] BlazoredModalInstance ModalInstance { get; set; }

private string _password = String.Empty;
private string _pwordIncorrect = "d-none";
private string _pwordRequired = "d-none";


private async Task Login()
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(_password))
    {
        _pwordRequired = "";
    }
    else
    {
        _pwordRequired = "d-none";
        Console.Write(_password);
        SHA1 hash = SHA1.Create(_password);
        bool ok = await TerritoryDataStore.CheckDoNotCallPasswordsAsync(hash.ToString());
        if (ok)
        {
            await ModalInstance.CloseAsync(ModalResult.Ok(true));
        }
        else
        {
            _pwordIncorrect = "";
        }
    }

}
```

}

The issue I face is that when I run the code, the variable Password is not really anything the error comes back as a null handling exception but if I debug I get a weird error when trying to see the value

> Exception of type
> 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shared.VSCodeDebugProtocol.ProtocolException'
> was thrown.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Should `bind="_password"` become `@bind="_password"`?

Comment: so it ends up this was the problem code
- SHA1 hash = SHA1.Create(_password);

The issue being that I could not see that the process was not doing what I wanted because of the VS exception. Once that cleared all became apparent.